# ASP Cannot display full contents of tables on Database - ADODB.Connection

Tags: database, web

It seems like silly question but I cannot find solution.

This implementation is display full content of each table on database using `ADODB.Connection`

```
'Display Tables'
Set rs = objConn.OpenSchema(20)
RPW("<table>")
RPW("<tr bgcolor=#888>")
    RPW("<td>Table</td>")
RPW("</tr>")

rs.MoveFirst
Do While Not rs.eof
    IF rs(3) = "TABLE" Then
        RPW("<tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>")
        RPW("<td>" & rs(2) & "</td>")
        RPW("</tr>")
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

Call DisplayTable(objConn, objRecd, "Family")
Call DisplayTable(objConn, objRecd, "PersonalInformation")
Call DisplayTable(objConn, objRecd, "Special")
%>
</body>
</html>
<%
Function RPW(text)
    Response.Write(text)
End Function

Function DisplayTable(objconn, objrecd, table)
P2SN("Display Tables")
    RPW("</table>")
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & table
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objrecd = objconn.Execute(strSQL)
    'Set objrecd.Open(strSQL), objConn

    If (objrecd.BOF And objrecd.EOF) Then
        P2SN("No Recoreds Found")
        'Response.End
    End If

    RPW("<table>")
    RPW("<tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>")
    For Each x In objrecd.Fields
        RPW("<td>" & x.Name & "</td>")
    Next
    RPW("</tr>")
    RPW("<tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>")
    For Each x In objrecd.Fields
        RPW("<td>" & x.Value & "</td>")
    Next
    RPW("</tr></table>")
End Function
%>
```

**Result here:**

[image]

But I have 8 people's information not only one.

Then I don't know what does the `OpenSchema(20)` mean.

Someone please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post `objRecd.GetString` result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Function DisplayTable(objconn, objrecd, table)
    P2SN("Display Tables")
    RPW("</table>")
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & table
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objrecd = objconn.Execute(strSQL)
    If (objrecd.BOF And objrecd.EOF) Then
        P2SN("No Recoreds Found")
    End If

    RPW("<table>")
    Do While Not objrecd.EOF
    RPW("<tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>")
    For Each x In objrecd.Fields
        RPW("<td>" & x.Name & "</td>")
    Next
    RPW("</tr>")
    RPW("<tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>")
    For Each x In objrecd.Fields
        RPW("<td>" & x.Value & "</td>")
    Next
    objRecd.MoveNext
    Loop
    RPW("</tr></table>")
End Function
```

Displaying all contents of tables, using `Loop` to look for individual value.

Comment: Use `objRecd.Fields("FieldsName")`. ex:) `objRecd.Fields("Age")`. I think you can find fields name automatically using `x.Name` and find value using `objRecd.Fields(x.Name)`